# Selenium WebDriver hangs when page not responding

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver

Is there any way to explicitly set a timeout value. I've used the following, but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30));
```

If I can create a new tab and close the current one, and/or stop the page loading when an exception occurs, that would be a sufficient workaround.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A helper class is available in the WebDriver support project. Using that you can wait till  the condition you passed to the "Untill" method is satisfied or it's times out after specified period(in this e.g. after 3 seconds)

```
IWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3))
IWebElement element = wait.Until(driver => driver.FindElement(By.Name("q")));
```

Install the support project via NuGet using the following command

```
Install-Package Selenium.Support
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a WPF (WinForms) app that runs my selenium tests. When I need to sleep an action I just call Thread.Sleep(someInteger). Have you tried that?

Answer (score 0):

If the driver is truly hanging, WebDriverWait won't work, as all it does is poll the driver with the condition specified.

An alternative is having the driver wrapped on a separate thread which has it's own timeout, and running the driver calls asynchronously. It's a bit of a convoluted solution but it works.